# Use GLib.HashTable in Genie

Tags: vala, genie

How can I access GLib.HashTable in Genie? I am trying to write a handler method for libsoup HTTP server. The query parameter is a GLib.HashTable. When I try to access query e.g. with

```
def search_handler (server : Soup.Server, msg : Soup.Message, path : string, 
                query : GLib.HashTable?, client : Soup.ClientContext)
 response_text : string = null
 if query is not null && query.contains("expr")
     response_text = get_search(query.get("expr"))
```

I got the error:

```
error: missing generic type arguments
    response_text = get_search(query.get("expr"))
                               ^^^^^
```

The only way I found is to make a new HashTable object:

```
p : GLib.HashTable of string, string = query
expr : string = p.get("expr")
```

What is the right way to handle this?

Comment: The proper solution in Vala is using "GLib.HashTable<string,string>?" (or whatever the correct types are) for the parameter type.  I think the Genie way to do that would be "GLib.HashTable? of string, string", but when I try that here I get a syntax error.  I don't know what the right answer is (perhaps it is a bug in Genie), but hopefully that helps you find it.

Answer (score 1):

My be you can try with : dict of string,string

```
var d = new dict of string,string
d["one"]="1"
d["two"]="2"
print "%s",d["one"]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

something like this

[indent=4]

```
init
    var h = new HashTable of string, int (str_hash, str_equal)
    h["foo"] = 123
    h["bar"] = 456

    foo ("foo", h)


def foo (key: string, hash: HashTable of string, int)
    // PUT HASHTABLE IN THE END
    if hash.contains (key)
        stdout.printf ("%s => %i", key, hash[key])
```